# Parsing different unicode files using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, cp1251

I have this particular HTML page having codec

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
```

Now When I am trying to parse this particular file using BeautifulSoup, it always returns NULL object.
I can convert it using:

```
page = codecs.open('file_name', 'r', 'cp1251')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
```

Now it's working fine. But in my collection, I have got pages consisting of both **UTF-8** and **windows-1251** charset types. So, I wanted to know what is the procedure to determine the charset of a particular HTML page, and convert it accordingly if it's in windows-1251 format ?

I found this:

```
soup.originalEncoding
```

But for that I need to load it into 'soup'. But there only it's returning 'None type object'. Any help would be highly appreciated.

I am using Python 2.7

**EDIT:**

Here is an example of what I am actually trying to say:

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

page=urllib2.urlopen(Page_link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

print soup.html.head.title
```

page having

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

correctly displays the title of the page.

Now if a page has

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
```

then the output is

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'

Now I can fix this using the codecs library as mentioned above. What I am trying to find out is how to determine the encoding in order to be able to apply it.

These are the two sites that am trying to crawl and gather certain informations:

http://www.orderapx.com/ and http://www.prpoakland.com/

Comment: You decoded the page to Unicode, not UTF8. UTF8 is another encoding, just like Windows-1251.. Can you show us sample source code? Does it really say `"charset=charset=..."` in the source?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I copied wrongly. I edited the line. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Also, is this BeautifulSoup 3 or 4? *Normally*, I'd expect BeautifulSoup to find the `<meta />` tag and detect the encoding for you.

Comment: BeautifulSoup 4.3.1 !

Comment: Right. BS4 can use [different HTML parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser); have you got `lxml` installed at all? BS4 will use that as the default if available. You can also try each of the other parsers to see if any works better for your specific content; see http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

Comment: Yes, I have lxml installed. Infact in the first place I tried to do the entire thing it lxml only, but since it seemed to be a bit more complicated to me, hence switched to BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Then the other tow parsers and see if any of those work better; switch between `'html.parser'` and `'html5lib'` (which is a separate install). If the HTML is malformed different parsers handle the repairing differently.

Comment: Ah, you are opening this with `urllib2`? Is there a `Content-Type` header at all for these pages?

Comment: Actually the entire dataset consists of 2000 pages collected from all over the web, different marketing websites. Hence I can't say whether all of them contain Content-Type header or not, but at least the few pages whose source codes I have actually seen, contains it. Assuming it is, for all the pages, what do you suggest ?

Comment: I'd look for a `Content-Type` header, and if present and containing a `charset=..` parameter, use that parameter to tell BeautifulSoup what codec to use. See http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings.

Comment: Yes ! It worked. Thank You very much for your valuable suggestions. Actually I was trying to determine the encoding using soup.originalEncoding (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Why can't Beautiful Soup print out the non-ASCII characters I gave it?) and it seems to return none type object always.

Comment: Glad to have been of help! I've summarized my advice into an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading your pages from the web; look for a content type header with `charset` parameter to see if the webserver already told you about the encoding:

```
charset = page.headers.getparam('charset')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), from_encoding=charset)
```

If no such parameter is present, `charset` is set to `None` and BeautifulSoup will fall back to guessing.

You can also try out [different parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser); if the HTML is malformed, different parsers will repair the HTML in different ways, perhaps allowing BeautifulSoup to detect the encoding better.